# Eclipse clone project

Tags: java, eclipse

How can i clone an existing project in a same workspace with different name in eclipse.

The import options does not work because of below error

```
"Some projects cannot be imported because they already exist in the workspace"
```

Comment: Did you try coping the files in your File Manager and then importing the copied files?

Comment: i'm looking for an option in ecliple, something like duplicate project. If i copy in file manager i believe i should copy outside the workspace and then import it

Comment: Two projects must have different names and the project name is specified in the `.project` file. Not sharing the `.project` file and renaming the project to make the project directory name differing from the project name before cloning the Git repository should work (because when importing a project, the folder name is used as project name if there is no `.project` file). Alternatively, you can edit the `.project` file in the cloned repository before importing the project.

Answer (score 0):

Rename the directory where the project is located. Directory must not have same workspace name